# Time computation in Millis is not producing the expected outcome. Can somebody help tell why?

Tags: java, date, time, business-logic

I have the following code that normally would take some instances of time, convert them to  milliseconds to make some fairly precise computations, and produce the equivalent day(s) between those times OR hour(s) between them as the case may be. I think the code best explains what I am trying to achieve. Following are some snippets...

```
private int hours = 0;

/* This is intended to get the days between 'startDate' and 'endDate'
 * and ensure it is between zero & the specified 'range' of days, inclusive*/
public int getPeriodBtw(Date startDate, Date endDate, int range)
{
    int daysBtw = 0;
    Calendar constantDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    constantDate.setTime(startDate);
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentDate.setTime(endDate);
    long rangePeriod = Period.ConvertDaysToMillis(range);
    long duration = (constantDate.getTimeInMillis() + rangePeriod) - currentDate.getTimeInMillis();
    daysBtw = (int)Period.ConvertMillisToDays(duration);
    if(duration >= 0 && duration <= rangePeriod)
    {
        if(daysBtw == 0){
            hours = (int)Period.ConvertMillisToHours(duration);
        }
    }
    return daysBtw;
}
```

Now, the logic above seems all knit tight and good to me, but surprisingly, I get odd results as `currentDate` changes. I mean, normally I would expect something like this... See the following Illustration;

If `constantDate = 10:00am`
If `range = 1 day` starting from `constantDate`
and lets say `currentDate = 2:00pm` on the same day (i.e within `range`),
then `daysBtw` should return  `= 0`
hours between `constantDate` and `currentDate` is  `4hrs` 
Now this means `currentDate` is  `4hrs` Less `range`,
Thus `duration` should be `1day(24hrs) - 4hrs = 20hrs`

Of course I think handling this in Millisecond offset from epoch wld be something like so;

`10:00am(millis) + 1day(millis) - 2:00pm(millis)` = `20hrs`

```
long duration = (constantDate.getTimeInMillis() + rangePeriod) - currentDate.getTimeInMillis();
hours = (int)Period.ConvertMillisToHours(duration);
```

so `hours` should return  `= 20`

Now, if `currentDate` changes to `3:00pm`, following the same logic previously described, shouldn't `hours = 19`???... Problem is, my program gets `hours = 21` instead.

I've been really confused as to what I might be doing wrong. Is the problem with my Logic???... Or is it somewhere in my Code???... I feel terribly bad admitting that I've spent a few hours on and off this thing that I know is rather simple, But time is not my friend as usual, and I have to move on to things less trivial. Any form of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks Y'all!

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through.  Can you reduce it to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org) which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, Thanks for being the one to let me know how I got on the wrong side of people. Was tryna avoid being asked for more code later. I've reduced the code the best I can without mangling its essence... I still look forward to solutions tho... Thanx!

Comment: @Sednus I fink they all wanna teach me how to properly use S-O. Good thing I got the drift... Have you any help to offer over my issue? Will be glad.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I did find a solution to this issue earlier on... Turned out it was due to; 
 
1. some bad logic on my side, and also 
2. some loss of precision when using `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` to convet Milliseconds to Days

```
TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(args, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

It still beats me why they had to make the `convert` method recieve its milliseconds argument as `long` and return days as `long` too, without creating an option to set the preferred `RoundingMode`.... Anyways, its been added to my short list of ( STAY-AWAY-FROM-IT ) API's. Lolz!